# CSS parallax scrolling with background image moving

Tags: html, css, parallax

Here is what my parallax scrolling currently looks like:

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm)

I have this:

```
background-image:url("http://google.com");
background-attachment: fixed;
```

i want this but i don't want to use the "materialize css" stuff: [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html)

where the `background-image` moves a little while you scroll up or down the page.

Answer (score 1):

To get this parallax effect, background images have to be placed on different elements. These elements additionally need to have defined background-attachment: fixed. By defining background-attachment the behavior and positioning of any background image can be changed.

Comment: Can you go a little further with your answer? Once you have placed the background image on a different element and given it the `background-attachment: fixed` property/value, how do you then change its scrolling speed (also called scrolling offset)?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this class to your image section

```
background:url('http://google.com') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover"
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the `materialize.css`, take a look at my example here

https://jsfiddle.net/sug65rh0/

HTML

```
<div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
  <p>Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. Nascetur per nec posuere turpis, lectus nec libero turpis nunc at, sed posuere mollis ullamcorper libero ante lectus, blandit pellentesque a, magna turpis est sapien duis blandit dignissim. Viverra interdum mi magna mi, morbi sociis. Condimentum dui ipsum consequat morbi, curabitur aliquam pede, nullam vitae eu placerat eget et vehicula. Varius quisque non molestie dolor, nunc nisl dapibus vestibulum at, sodales tincidunt mauris ullamcorper, dapibus pulvinar, in in neque risus odio. Accumsan fringilla vulputate at quibusdam sociis eleifend, aenean maecenas vulputate, non id vehicula lorem mattis, ratione interdum sociis ornare. Suscipit proin magna cras vel, non sit platea sit, maecenas ante augue etiam maecenas, porta porttitor placerat leo.</p>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-2">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">LESS HEIGHT</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-3">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">COOL!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}
.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax2.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax3.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #111;
}
```

Comment: hi your example did not work...